# What is this green board?

Tags: robotics

[image]
Hi I'm new to arduino and robotics itself. I have no idea what this giant green board is in the middle of the robot. I really need help!

Comment: In what way is this question related to the Arduino?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The green board is probably a custom PCB that controls the vehicle. Unfortunately, the image does not have enough quality to determine much else.

Comment: Create such PCB is possible in kitchen over one evening without anything costy (maybe except laser printer, if you want high density mask, but permanent marker can go long way too) , I made a lot of similar PCBs (but little smaller, just to fit my needs), like  https://wiki.gilhad.cz/mediawiki/images/8/8f/H-mustek-2-med.png

Answer (score 1):

It's a sheet of [FR-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FR-4) clad in copper, with much of the copper etched off to form a PCB. That is then coated in green UV cured paint (solder resist) and components are attached.

Other things are then plugged into it.

What function it performs depends on what the designer designed it to do.